# Hibernate data filter in XML many to one mapping file

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am wondering how to add a data filter in many to one mapping.

Putting a sample code:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name = "Employee" table = "EMPLOYEE">
      
      <meta attribute = "class-description">
         This class contains the employee detail. 
      </meta>
      
      <id name = "id" type = "int" column = "id">
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>
      
      <property name = "firstName" column = "first_name" type = "string"/>
      <property name = "lastName" column = "last_name" type = "string"/>
      <property name = "salary" column = "salary" type = "int"/>
      <many-to-one name = "address" column = "address" 
         class="Address" not-null="true"/>
         
   </class>

   <class name = "Address" table="ADDRESS">
      
      <meta attribute = "class-description">
         This class contains the address detail. 
      </meta>
      
      <id name = "id" type = "int" column = "id">
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>
      
      <property name = "street" column = "street_name" type = "string"/>
      <property name = "city" column = "city_name" type = "string"/>
      <property name = "state" column = "state_name" type = "string"/>
      <property name = "zipcode" column = "zipcode" type = "string"/>
      
   </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

basically, I want to add a filter that fetches the employee who lives in a city(ex: Chennai)

```
  <filter name="cityFilter" condition="city=:cityFilterParam)"/>
```

Can someone please tell me how it makes it possible?

Comment: looks like there is no option available with hibernate!!

Comment: Did you try that : https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html#objectstate-filters ? Or is it a different question ?